# How can I order results which have some value equals zero in the end, while other results are ascending?

Tags: sql

Let me explain: I need to sort a list in ascending order, while results leave less than zero at the end.

Example:

```
**Field**  
2  
5  
15  
19  
0  
-5  
-19
```

I **think** I can join result of two queries using UNION, but I want to do using only one, is it possible?

Any answer telling how to order thay way will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following ORDER BY at the end of your normal query (no union)

```
order by (case when field>0 then 0 else 1 end), field
```

Or, if your database system's SQL flavor supports implicit conversion of booleans to integers:

```
order by (field <= 0), field
```

Comment: Can you explain me what means the 0 and 1 inside an order by? In using MySql, by the way.

Comment: @MarceloAssis - The ORDER BY is sorting first by the result of the CASE expression, then by the field value. There is nothing special about the values of 0 and 1. Any values could be used as long as the value that is assigned to positive field values sorts before the value that is assigned to non-positive field values.